# C# creating another instance of subclass - Reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm reposting a question I've just asked, but want to re-ask this question in a more concise way as I think I was causing some confusion.

I have a base class: RoomObject.
I have two subclasses: Bed and Table, which inherit from RoomObject.

I have a variable currentObject, which is of type RoomObject, but will actually hold either an instance of Bed or Table (RoomObject is never instantiated itself).

How can I clone my currentObject, without knowing its full type?

i.e. if currentObject is a Bed, I want to clone the Bed using

```
currentObject = new Bed(currentObject);
```

and if currentObject is a Table, I want to use

```
currentObject = new Table(currentObject);
```

I could use reflection, by calling Activator.CreateInstance(currentObject.GetType()), and then copy across any attributes I need, but this seems messy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the pattern known as the *virtual constructor*, or a *cloning method*.

Add a virtual method to `RoomObject` that returns a copy of the current object:

```
abstract RoomObject Clone();
```

Now implement this method in `Bed` to return `new Bed(...)`, and in the `Table` to return `new Table(...)`. Pass whatever parameters necessary to the constructors of `Bed` and `Table` to copy what's in the current object.

.NET has an interface `ICloneable` that is commonly used to implement this pattern. A small disadvantage of that approach is that `Clone` must return `object`, not `RoomObject`, so if you need `RoomObject`, you'd need to cast it.

Comment: What about `ICloneable`? It's the built-in interface for doing such things.

Comment: Ah, OK! yes, this makes perfect sense. Thanks, and apologies for the double post of question.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer That returns `object` not `RoomObject`.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer That's a great note, thank you very much! I added `ICloneable` to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Servy Hey, you like discussions. `object` but `RoomObject` after all. And if you don't like `ICloneable` just make another interface that also implements `ICloneable` like `ICloneable<T>`... But returning `object` doesn't mean that OP can't eventually cast to `RoomObject`. BTW I don't know why I'm discussing this with you as you discuss everything...

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yeah. And I've an additional improvement for you: a custom `ICloneable<T>` that also implements `ICloneable` which adds a typed `Clone()` method.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the best things about reflection: The ability to create an object without your client code knowing what type it is. Sometimes it can get messy, or even slow down the code at times, but--if used correctly--will make your code a lot more manageable.

For example, take a look at [the Factory Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817667.aspx), and how one can implement it [with Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164170.aspx) and [here as well](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yDEmb5XYc_s)

Comment: Depending on the factory, there's a better choice for that: generic constraints. `where T : new()` which allows you to call the generic type constructor without reflection.

Answer (score 1):

I think one solution would be implement ICloneable interface for all your objects. Here's some sample code:

```
class RoomObject : ICloneable
{
    public abstract object Clone();
}

class Bed : ICloneable
{
    public override object Clone()
    {
        return new Bed();
    }
}

class Table : ICloneable
{
    public override object Clone()
    {
        return new Table();
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        RoomObject ro = /* from some other places*/
        RoomObject newOne = ro.Clone() as RoomObject;  /* here's what you what */
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, you provided some samples... but isn't this the same answer as dasblinkenlight one...?

Comment: well, we posted at exactly the same time. Both answers are basically based on the same principle but as you said, I have sample code. :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of that, implement the [`ICloneable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx) interface that's out-of-the-box on .NET Framework as others said in their answers.

Since `ICloneable.Clone()` method returns `object`, what about a custom `ICloneable<T>` that also implements `ICloneable`?

```
public interface ICloneable<T> : ICloneable
    where T : class
{
    T TypedClone();
}

public class MyCloneableObject : ICloneable<MyCloneableObject>
{
     public string Some { get; set; }

     public object Clone()
     {
         MyCloneableObject clone = new MyCloneableObject { Some = this.Some };
     }

     public MyCloneableObject TypedClone()
     {
          return (MyCloneableObject)Clone();
     }
}
```

Later, in your code...

```
MyCloneableObject some = new MyCloneableObject();

if(some is ICloneable<MyCloneableObject>)
{
    MyCloneableObject myClone = some.TypedClone();

    // .. or the standard `Clone()`:
    myClone = (MyCloneableObject)some.Clone();
}
```

Implementing both built-in and custom interface is a good idea, as your cloneable will operate with other libraries that may accept `ICloneable` implementations.

Finally, rather than using reflection, this case should be solved in design-time. I would argue that doing with reflection should be done if you can't modify the library containing the `ICloneable` wannabe.